# Can we Write Image file to camera preview in android application

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-camera2, v4l2loopback

How can i write image or video data which is stored in a file to a camera preview using an android application.
Video should be replaced of camera preview (camera preview is taken from camera) when we launch camera.

Is there any Camera APIs which we can write to a camera?